# Модуль Kohana "Комментарии": Call to undefined method Request::instance

Tags: php, kohana

Установил [модуль](https://github.com/theshock/kohana-modules/tree/master/comments) для коханы. Установил на страницу, но при добавлении комментария пишет

> ErrorException [ Fatal Error ]: Call to undefined method Request::instance()

```
protected function redirect (Model_Comment $comment) {
        $r = Request::instance();
        $r->redirect($r->uri);
    }
```

Что делать? Я пытался `Request::initial()`, но не работает

Answer (score 1):

Проверьте [этот](http://dev.kohanaframework.org/projects/kohana3-core/repository/entry/classes/kohana/request.php?rev=3.2%2Fmaster) вариант

```
$r = Request::current();
```

> `/**
>  * @var  Request  currently executing request instance
>  */
> public static $current;`

Comment: Iron, теперь пишет ErrorException [ Notice ]: Undefined property: Request::$uri

Answer (score 0):

```
Request::current()->headers;
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение.